# How to substitute broken Images with JavaScript in a HTML document?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, replace

I'm wondering how you can substitute the src-property (or delete the whole img-node) with JavaScript, if the browser is realizing, that the image beyond the image-src-property doesn't exist (any more).

For example:

```
<div id="foo">
   <img src="bar">
</div>
```

And the img-tag is pointing to nowhere. In some browser, esp. the iE, are showing a "no image" cross. I prefer to substitute bar with an alternative image url or substitute the img-node with a *nbsp*.

I found an [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images), that doesn't really worked for me.

Please suggest me solutions only with PrototypeJS or raw JS (its a project which is using PrototypeJS and I don't wanna overload it with other frameworks).

Comment: "I found an approach, that doesn't really worked for me." - why?

Comment: What part of the linked solution doesn't work for you? Seems like a good solution.

Comment: I really don't know. Honestly I copy and pasted it and it was without any effect. - But it's interesting anyway, if there are more event handler like onerror. If not: Workarounds that could act as handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just use an `onerror` handler for the image, and inside the handler, either delete the node or change the src:

```
<img src="..." id="img-1"
     onerror="document.getElementById('img-1').src='working image';">
```

Or alternately:

```
<img src="..." id="img-1"
     onerror="document.getElementById('img-1').parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('img-1'));">
```

It's probably better to write that as an event handler and attach it to all images in the document.

Comment: I've tried the first solution and it works fine.
But what about the IDs if you have dynamic-many img's in your document? Can't you use _this_ or something else?

Comment: If you write an event handler, and attach that to the image, then you can use `this`.  In an inline script, `this` will refer to the `window` object.

Comment: The onerror property is not strict xhtml, so I had to vote down for this answer.

Comment: seriously?  perhaps the title of this question should mention strict XHTML